# ClearCase: How to find elements that do NOT have a particular label

Tags: version-control, command-line, clearcase

I'm looking for a ClearCase command that will list all the elements that are visible in my current view, but do **NOT** have a particular label applied to them.

Say for example, most of the elements that are visible in my view have *LABEL_X* applied to them.  I want a list of those elements that do not have *LABEL_X*.

I obviously need to use `cleartool find`, but the usage and ClearCase man page baffle me in terms of how to construct a query like this.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback: I completed the answer to include the 'nxn' (no extended pathname) option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
ct find -all -ele '! lbtype_sub(LABEL_X)' -print
ct find -ele '! lbtype_sub(LABEL_X)' -print
```

Notes:

- ct stands for cleartool
- Unix syntax here (for windows, replace simple quotes with double quotes)
- beware of the space between `!` and `lbtype_sub` (in winodws you do not need the space)
- **`-ele`** very IMPORTANT to get only one occurrence of a given file (and not all the different versions of a file matching a criteria)

`-ele` limits the search to elements, not versions (that would trigger a *lot more* results with versions involved...)

`-all` list all elements included "deleted" (that is "unreferenced") ones.
The second line lists only *visible* elements (in the current view)

You should execute those second command lines on the sub-directory of your choice within a given ClearCase (snapshot or dynamic view): all files within that sub-directory (and sub-sub directories...) matching the cirteria will be listed.

Warnings:

- files *and directories* are listed. If you want only files, add `-type f` to the query:

  ct find -type f -ele '!lbtype_sub(LABEL_X)' -print
- what is displayed is the extended path for elements, that is the name of the file followed with `@@`.

To list only the name without `@@`, use '`-nxn`' (no extendedpathname option)

```
ct find -nxn -ele '!lbtype_sub(LABEL_X)' -print
```

Another more complex but also more complete way to list only the name without `@@`, is to use `descr -fmt`. For instance:

```
ct find . -ele "!lbtype_sub(LABEL_X)" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%En %d\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""

ct find . -ele '! lbtype_sub(LABEL_X)' -exec 'cleartool descr -fmt "%En %d\n" "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

would give you (in windows or unix syntax) the date and name of the files and directories not labeled LABEL_X.

With that '`descr -fmt`' display, you can combine any kind of information and presentation you want for the result.

Comment: Thanks, the -ele was the trick.  I was trying to use -ver.

Also, I was able to get the filenames without the extended path (@@) by adding -nxn (no extended naming symbol):

ct find . -ele '!lbtype_sub(LABEL_X)' -nxn -print

Comment: -nxn! I forgot about that one: much simpler than cleartool descr -fmt!... Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I couldn't get code formatting to work in the comment box: see below.

Answer (score 2):

Above works, but remember to specifiy -cview to get JUST the current view, otherwise you'll get files from all the other views as well.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use the following on my Linux clearcase install:

```
cleartool find -cview -all -version '\!lbtype(LABEL_X)' -print
```

The syntax from VonC's post did not work properly with the "!" not being escaped.