# Get elements of a label which is present only in the current version but not in any other previous versions

Tags: clearcase

how do I get elements of a label which is present only in the current version but not in any other previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't be possible with ClearCase, considering a label can only be associated with *one* version of an element (an "element" is a file or directory).

You could try and search for a label only applied on *one* element and not applied on any other element though.

> how do i get all changed elements of a label from the current branch since last integration branch?

The query described in "[How can I find all elements on a branch with version LATEST that has no label applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5209923/6309)" can be of interest.

Simpler queries are also available on this [IBM page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rcss=faqtt_1Q09&uid=swg21124425):

#### Find all element versions with a given label that are not on a given branch:

> Windows:

```
cleartool find -all -version "lbtype_sub(MYLABEL) && !brtype(mybranch)" -print
```

> UNIX and Linux:

```
cleartool find -all -version 'lbtype_sub(MYLABEL) && !brtype(mybranch)' -print
```

Comment: thanks for the info...how do i get all changed elements of a label from the current branch since last integration branch?

Comment: i wanted only the elements of a label since rebasing the branch. That is all the elements of a new label on a branch after rebasing the branch shouldnt contain the elements present before rebasing

Comment: also could you let me know how to find all the attribute types associated with a particular label?