# ClearCase UCM: Branch created of file that is not part of an activity. What happened?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have somehow created a branch of a file in clearcase UCM that is not part of an activity.  I have no idea how to reproduce this, but my stream is showing many files with this symptom.  How can I find these files, remove them, and prevent it from happening again in the future?

Here is an example of one such file, names redacted to protect the innocent:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx.cpp@@/main/xxx-integration/xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx/0 Rule: .../xxx-xxxxxxx/LATEST
```

A `ct lsact -long | grep <filename>` returns no results.

Update:
I used a find command to track down all the files that are on the branch given (and redacted) above, though I still do not understand the issue.

Per VonC's answer, where is what I ended up doing:

```
cleartool find . -type f -version "version(.../xxx/LATEST)&&version(.../xxx/0)" -print | tee ~/tmp/files2
```

I then read through the list of files generated to make sure they made sense, then I verified they were not attached to an activity and removed the versions:

```
cat ~/tmp/files2 | while read
do 
    if [ -z "$(ct describe -fmt "%[activity]p" $REPLY)" ]
    then 
        ct rmbranch -f ${REPLY%/0}
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can happen ig those file were checkout in a base ClearCase view, ie a non-UCM view, withg a simple config spec:

```
element * .../xxx-integration/LATEST -mkbranch xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

You can use a find command similar to "[How can I find all elements on a branch with version LATEST that has no label applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194043/6309)".
The difference is: for each version found, you need to describe it in order to check if there is an activity attached to it or not (with a [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)):

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[activity]p" "$CLEARCASE_XPN"
```

Comment: Perfect.  I knew you would come to the rescue!

Comment: What I don't understand is how changes ended up in version 0.  Any idea how that may have happened?

Comment: @Seamus this is usually a sign of a `checkout`, followed by an `unco` (`undo checkout`), which leaves a version 0 on the newly created branch. You can delete those version 0 following http://stackoverflow.com/a/18183902/6309.