# Clearcase: list element labels in a view

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

Using ClearCase, I would like to retrieve all the elements of the VOB that **do not** have a particular label.

I am trying to do something similar to the following but it doesn't work. 
Any help ?

```
cleartool find . -elem '( ! (lbtype(MYLABEL)))' -print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a query similar to:

```
cleartool find . -elem '! lbtype_sub(MYLABEL)' -print
```

From [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) and [query_language](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm):

```
lbtype_sub (label-type-name)
```

> With elements: TRUE if the element has a version that is labeled label-type-name.

More details in "[ClearCase: How to find elements that do NOT have a particular label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439959/clearcase-how-to-find-elements-that-do-not-have-a-particular-label)"