# Cleartool only list labeled files of a folder

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have a folder in clearcase, that contains 100+ files, some of them have labels, the others not. I need a fast way to get all labeled files only.
Right now i tried using `ct ls -short path\to\folder` to list all files and then i have used `ct lsvtree path\to\folder\file` to check, wether the file contains labels or not. The way i am currently using works, but it's very slow, is there a simple command to detect all the files with labels?

Answer (score 2):

The IBM page "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)" has many examples, like:

```
cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(REL1)}' -print
```

That will find files with one of their versions having label `REL1`.
The reverse search is "[How to find elements that do NOT have a particular label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/442130/6309)"

As a quick workaround, you could:

- [list labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3342390/6309)

  ```
  cleartool lstype -kind lbtype -invob vob_path_and_name -short
  ```
- for each one:

  ```
  cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(alabel)}' -print
  ```

To quicken the all process a bit, you could group several labels togethers:

```
 cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(alabel)||lbtype_sub(alabel2)||...}' -print
```

Comment: Ok this is useful when the label name is known. Is there a way just like "if has a label"? Or some regex pattern like `*`, because the label name is not known before :/

Comment: @ThomasRichter No wildcard possible, as illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3342688/6309

Comment: Tanks. That is unfortunate. Ok do you still have an idea how to accomplish a solution?

Comment: @ThomasRichter I have edited the answer to propose a simple workaround. I am still checking if there is a more native solution though.

Comment: @ThomasRichter no obvious native solution, let's wait for other ClearCase speciallists to chime in.